# Format property for custom control in winforms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a custom control with the following property

```
public ulong Mask { get; set; }
```

When I use the control, the property shows up in the editor as a decimal number.

[image]

Is there a way to display this property value as a hexidecimal?  If there's a way to break up the hexidecimal number into groups of four digits, that would be even better.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if `[DebuggerDisplay(...)]` attribute on the property will help?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That doesn't affect the designer display, unfortunately.

Comment: You need a [TypeConverter] to convert back-and-forth from the string.  Use the built-in [UInt64Converter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/UInt64Converter.cs,8b5fd45d6ff9654c) as a guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UInt64Converter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.uint64converter(v=vs.110).aspx) provides most of what you need as it supports conversions from a hexadecimal format. All that is necessary is to override the `ConvertTo` to method to display as hexadecimal.

```
public class UInt64HexConverter : UInt64Converter
{
    private static Type typeUInt64 = typeof(UInt64);

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType");
        }

        if (((destinationType == typeof(string)) && (value != null)) && typeUInt64.IsInstanceOfType(value))
        {
            UInt64 val = (UInt64)value;
            return "0x" + val.ToString("X");
        }

        if (destinationType.IsPrimitive)
        {
            return Convert.ChangeType(value, destinationType, culture);
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
class BitControl : Control
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(UInt64HexConverter))]
    public ulong Mask { get; set; }
}
```